SSL Error occurs with pip commands due to pypi nvidia repository
I have pip version 24.0.0 installed, even before upgrade, normal pip commands aren't working.
For example:
pip install tensorflow

results in:
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1006)'))': /compute/redist/tensorflow/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1006)'))': /compute/redist/tensorflow/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1006)'))': /compute/redist/tensorflow/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1006)'))': /compute/redist/tensorflow/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1006)'))': /compute/redist/tensorflow/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com/tensorflow/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='developer.download.nvidia.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /compute/redist/tensorflow/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1006)'))) - skipping

Does anyone has a solution to this? This problem occured recently.
I've attached the image below.
Also it works fine with my mobile internet, but when I use wifi, I face this problem.
The solutions or methods I've tried so far:

adding --trusted-host pypi.ngc.nvidia.com 
adding pypi.ngc.nvidia.com to pip.ini as an extra-index-url and also setting it as trusted host

None of the above worked.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please specify what your install commandline was and report the error you get as text. Sharing .png links on a forum like this is not a safe practice.

If you are trying to use Python within a company network, your company's security policy might hinder your network communication. If this is the case, you can directly call the SSL certificate in Python using os.environ['REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE'], os.environ['SSL_CERT_FILE'] or insert your certificate information directly into Python's cacert.pem to certificate your SSL comunication. But be sure to ask your network manager in company first
